# RuntimeError: Cannot find the MXNet library

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, mxnet

I want to create executable for my code where i'm using mxnet with pyinstaller.

I got this error

```
File "mxnet/libinfo.py", line 74, in find_lib_path
RuntimeError: Cannot find the MXNet library.
List of candidates:
/home/rit/test/exe/dist/test/libmxnet.so
/home/rit/test/exe/dist/test/libmxnet.so
/home/rit/test/exe/dist/test/mxnet/libmxnet.so
/home/rit/test/exe/dist/test/mxnet/../../lib/libmxnet.so
/home/rit/test/exe/dist/test/mxnet/../../build/libmxnet.so
```

Added libmxnet.so though spec file but gave me PyInstallerImportError

Uninstalled mxnet though pip and copied python3.5/dist-packages/mxnet to my project same problem facing.

```
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll '/home/rit/test/exe/dist/test/libmxnet.so'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

Now what is dynlib/dll? How to resolve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MXNet](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/index.html) needs external binaries to be fed when you freeze it. You can use [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag to add libmxnet files to your executable:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data="<python_path>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mxnet/*.so*:./mxnet" script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux, can run like me.

```
find / -name "libmxnet.so"
export MXNET_LIBRARY_PATH={result of you find}
```

my find result is like this:

```
/opt/apps/mxnet/build/libmxnet.so
/usr/local/mxnet/libmxnet.so
```

so I will do:

```
export MXNET_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mxnet/libmxnet.so
```